# JDom XML Filtering

Tags: java, xml, jdom

I'm trying to count how many certain elements the document has:

```
Iterator<?> processDescendants = doc.getDescendants(new ElementFilter("a")); 

while(processDescendants.hasNext()) {
   numPending++;
}

processDescendants = doc.getDescendants(new ElementFilter("b")); 

while(processDescendants.hasNext()) {
   numPending++;
}
```

There has to be an easier way... such as:

```
processDescendants = doc.getDescendants(new ElementFilter("a|b")); // something like Regex maybe?
```

Anyone can help? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are essentially two ways to do it. The easy way is to just walk the elements...

```
Iterator<?> processDescendants = doc.getDescendants(new ElementFilter()); 

while(processDescendants.hasNext()) {
   Element e =  processDescendants.Next();
   string currentName = e.getTagName();
   if( currentName.equals("a") || currentName.equals("b") )
   {
       numPending++;
   }
}
```

Or you can implement your own Filter to add the functionality

```
import org.jdom.filter.Filter;
import org.jdom.Element;

public class ElementRegexFilter implements Filter {

    private String regex = "";

    public ElementRegexFilter( String regex )
    {
        this.regex = regex;
    }

    public boolean matches( Object o )
    {
        if( o instanceof Element )
        {
            String ElementName = ((Element) o).getName();
            return ElementName.matches( regex );
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: After getting the customized filter done. How can we use it. The matches method is automatically called ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is, but you can implement your own  [Filter](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/filter/Filter.html) for the JDOM parser, something like MatchABElementFilter, and make the match() method return "true" for objects of type element with name "a" or "b"

Answer (score 1):

There is a declarative way to do what you want. The XPath expression for it is `//a | //b`.

JDOM includes [a utility class for making XPath queries](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/xpath/XPath.html), you get back a list of matching nodes and can call `size` on the list to get your count.